# Enabling Text Selection in Compose LazyColumn by selection container

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, textselection, lazycolumn, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column

I previously used a WebView to display a long text and style each word based on some business logic. However, I recently transformed this HTML content into a list of sentences and utilized a LazyColumn to present it in my Compose application.

One of the features I cherished in my previous implementation was the ability to select text and utilize the pop-up options for actions like copying or sharing.

I've attempted to wrap my LazyColumn in a SelectionContainer within Jetpack Compose, but it's currently preventing me from selecting text across different items in the list.

I'm curious if there is a way to retain the same text selection behavior in my new Compose structure. Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried these ones so far:

```
  LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    content = {
        items(sentenceList) { index ->
            SelectionContainer {
                Text(
                    text = sentenceList[index]
                )
            }
        }
    }
)
```

and this:

```
SelectionContainer {
  LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        content = {
            items(sentenceList) { index ->
                    Text(
                        text = sentenceList[index]
                    )
                }
            }
    )
 }
```

update1:

I should mention that the second option does work, but there's an issue that arises when you try to scroll up and down and then attempt to long-press for text selection again; strangely, it stops working.

Comment: I have tried the second option is working fine as you described like copy,share,delete, etc

Comment: hey @ChiragThummar, thanks for your comment. second option works but I forgot to mention if you try to scroll down and up and then again long press to select, it won't work anymore weirdly.
can you confirm this too?

Comment: if you want to maintain the text selection then you should use it inside the item block

Comment: No, I don't want text selection to persist during scrolling. The test scenario is this: try to select the text, then dismiss the popup. Next, scroll down to the end of the list and scroll up again. After that, attempt to select the text once more. it stops working for me. @ChiragThummar

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be missing `State` of `LazyColumn`. I have tried below code and it works for me.

**Try This**

```
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
 fun TestPreview() {
    LazyColumn(
        state = rememberLazyListState(),
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        content = {
            items(65) { index ->
                SelectionContainer {
                    Text(
                        text = "I have pasted long text for text selection demo."
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    )

}
```

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work (compose version 1.8.2). `SelectionContainer` must be outside the `LazyColumn` of course. But even if it is, the problem is when you try to select sometimes you can't do it.

Comment: There is no compose versions 1.8.2 https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose

Comment: yes, mistake about version. But no matter - on last version this solution doesn't work for me. Still trying to find solution...